# He is coming straight [ to \ for \ at ] me

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

We generally use **to** for showing movement.

> He is coming straight **to** me.

But Cambridge dictionary says:

> The dog seemed to be coming at \ for me.

Can I use **to** instead?

Comment: "to" only indicates direction. "at" (or "for") suggests the intention to attack. We have other pairs of verbs working in the same way (*shout to/at - point to/at*).

Comment: @Gustavson -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in some contexts, but not for others:

> I am coming at Brazil
>
> I am coming to Brazil

Clearly, the first one is not correct, maybe because you can't use *at* when referring to long-distance places, only with short-distance places such as:

> Come at me!

Either one sounds appropriate in the examples you used though.
However, *For* doesn't express the same meaning as *To* and *At*. *For*, in such contexts, expresses a meaning of purpose - the reason why you are doing so.

If you say:

> I am coming to Brazil for you

I understand that the reason why you are traveling to Brazil is because you may want to see me or something like that.